# Stanford NER training on Tweets

Tags: stanford-nlp, opennlp, tweets, named-entity-recognition, named-entity-extraction

I am trying to train my own model on tweets and in my model I care about NEs inside hashtags. However, I can't think of a way that makes the tool actually learn such patterns in the data. Here is an example training record for OpenNLP:

```
        RAW Text   ►   Wright State is in #DaytonOH

OpenNLP Training   ►   <START>Wright State<END> is in #<START>Dayton<END><START>OH<END>
```

Now, if I prepare the same text for Stanford NER following [this link](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml#a):

```
Wright   LOC
State    LOC
is       O
in       O
#        O
Dayton   LOC
OH       LOC
```

Would that be OK? How can we make it work for character level instead of only token level? Do you think the CRF module is going to learn such patterns? Or should we just ignore hashtags?

Thanks in advance.

-H

Comment: I think the problem you need to solve is in the tokenization of the input - as most tokenizers I suspect will treat a hashtag as a single word. You might have more luck training as normal (as examples), but extend the tokenizer some how to split a hashtag into separate tokens where possible (which might be harder if all lower case). I haven't used the stanford library much but the OpenNLP tokeniser would be relatively easy to extend.

Comment: What entity do you want the #tag to be?

Comment: So the idea is that we want to be able to spot the entities inside a hashtag. Since we are operating on a different level inside the hashtag I am not sure it would work without breaking up the hashtag and then spot the entities inside them (as what Rhinds pointed out).

Comment: Dealing with hashtags like this is effectively a word segmentation issue of the kind you also get with languages like Chinese or Japanese. Unfortunately it is not something you get out of the box with either Stanford NLP or OpenNLP. By default, they will treat the hashtag as one token and label entities at the token level. Changing this requires more than the kind of regex-based tokenization that they both use – something more like the techniques that a lexicon-based or sequence model word segmenter uses.

Comment: Thank you Dr. Manning for the answer.